# Cleaning bathroom tiles affected with hard water stains

Tags: bathroom, tile

The walls in my bathroom have been badly affected by hard water.

[image]

The tiles have not been cleaned in the last ten years (please do not ask me why). Last year, the water supply in our locality was upgraded, and now we get soft water devoid of excess iron.

Cleaning these tiles is a very big problem. I've already tried all commercial chemicals which advertise effective cleaning of tiles, but with no positive results. Youtube remedies like using vinegar and baking soda have also yielded no results.

The only option I'm left with us using concentrated acid, but I don't want to use it, because it'll destroy the colour of the tiles completely.

Any idea how I can clean the tiles without acid?

Comment: you might also consider asking here https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cleaning

Comment: A product called WHINK will remove all of this.  It may take a few bottles of it to accomplish the entire task, but repeated use will take the stains off the tile.

Comment: After desired results  - using WHINK & rinsing thoroughly, use Scrubbing Bubbles Extra Strength to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

It needs to be something with acid in it like CLR or Whink. Read instructions thoroughly!!!!

Comment: I agree I have used CLR with great results. +Guess I should have read all the answers I said the same

Answer (score 0):

I have had great luck with a product called CLR calcium, lime and rust remover. As bad as the tile looks CLR will remove those stains without damaging the color of the tiles. It may take several applications but I have cleaned up worse in only an hour or so. I use gloves and a large sponge soak the sponge and wet the discolored surfaces wait a few minutes and repeat you will notice the stains starting to disipear keep repeating until clean and rince.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a product called Rust-be-gone? I've used it in my rust stained dishwasher and it worked great. Here's a link: http://red-b-gone.com/instructions.html